# Automatic Defender token on account creation

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, vpn

I'm trying to fully automate our account creation procedure on my work and everything is almost done and operational but the only thing i'm stuck on is the automatically assign a VPN token for the user in Active Directory.

The VPN defender we are using is One Identity's Defender and there is a administration software for it to assign tokens but the problem i have is that i need to say what exakt token the account should be assigned too.

The tokens are all reachable inside of the AD structure, and i could of course just choose one of them that is not already used every time but that would destroy the automation of the software.
The Software also comes with a built in Defender tab inside of the AD named [Defender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNmG2.png) where you can click program and it automatically assigns one of the free tokens that are available but this should also be able to be done without accessing the UI of the AD.

Is there anyone else who has done this before?
The only documentation i can find about this is the PDF in https://docplayer.net/1841144-Powershell-management-for-defender.html

The software i am creating is written in C# but if someone has done this in pure powershell and would like to help me with a few things would be awesome too.

Thanks
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You *can* call PowerShell commands from C#, but it's painful. I hate it.

It does look like Defender has a web service that you can use: https://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/defender/5.8/administrator-guide/74#TOPIC-348638

A web service is much more reasonable approach from .NET. I assume you have a support contract with One Identity. You can probably ask them for help in using it.